# jQuery: get inline style top position value into a variable

Tags: jquery

The style attribute always stumps me, because there are many values in the style attribute. Anyway, please see below my markup I'm trying to adjust...

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-default fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 798px; height: 542px; position: fixed; top: 82px; left: 20px; display: block; ">
```

As you can see I am trying to adjust the style: top: 82px; value. How can I get this value so I can add a value onto of it? Please see below the instance in how I am using this.

I would like the `currentTop` variable to some how get the current top inline position of the `.fancybox-wrap` div?

```
$("a.gallery-thumb").fancybox({
  afterLoad : function() {
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(info) {
      var scrollPosition = info.scrollTop,
      currentTop = /* how can I get the current top inline position? */ ;
      $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', (scrollPosition + currentTop) + 'px');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.fancybox-wrap').css('top', '+='+scrollPosition +'px');
```

Comment: Really? will this add the scrollPosition variable to the current top value?

Comment: I'd say yes. The easiest way to check is to try isn't it? If you don't like this version you can first retrieve the current position like this : `var current = $('.fancybox-wrap').css('top');`

Comment: Awesome - that is a nice little trick. += What do you call this?

Comment: Joshc it is said to be assignement operator

Comment: Yes, more info here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Answer (score 2):

You can get it using the below

```
$('.fancybox-wrap').css('top');
```

and sum it with the scrolltop.

Comment: Thank you this works too - I didnt realise css works both ways like this..!